# Try/Catch help, end of statement expected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

Quite new to the VB world and I'm working on homework.  I'm trying to set up a nested try/catch block to make sure the values that come from 3 text boxes are valid values for calculation.  I am stuck though, as I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a "End of statement expected" error. All 3 lines of the try block have the squiggly line underneath them. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click

    Dim FutureValueDecimal, InvestmentAmountDecimal, InterestRateDecimal As Decimal
    Dim YearsInteger As Integer

    Try InvestmentAmountDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InvestmentAmountTextBox.text)

          Try InterestRateDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InterestRateTextBox.text)

            Try YearsInteger = Integer.Parse(yearsTextBox.text)
            Catch InvalidYears As FormatException
                MsgBox("Please enter a valid number of years", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                YearsTextBox.SelectAll()
            End Try

        Catch InvalidInterest As FormatException
            MsgBox("Please enter a valid interest rate.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
            InterestRateTextBox.SelectAll()
        End Try
    Catch InvalidAmount As FormatException
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid investment amount.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try

    FutureValueDecimal = InvestmentAmountDecimal * (1D + InterestRateDecimal) ^ YearsInteger

            FutureValueTextBox.Text = FutureValueDecimal.ToString("C")



End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting a linebreak between `Try` and the next statement (e.g. `InvestmentAmountDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InvestmentAmountTextBox.text)`).

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.  The weird thing is that even if I comment out the two inside try/catches and try something simple like 'InvestmentAmountDecimal += 1' on the outside one, I still get the same error.

Comment: @Kris There are two possible reasons for the book you are using not mentioning that they need to be on seprate lines and showing them on the same line, neither of which are good. 1) The author didn't know better. 2) The publisher changed the formatting and the author never fixed it (possibly because of reason 1). The book should have a contact email address either for the author or the publisher...send something to them to get it corrected for future printings!

Comment: @scott dorman  I'm going to go with the publisher messed up somehow. Both authors have their PhD in computer science so I'm pretty sure they knew better.  I will definitely shoot the publisher a note; this is not some ordinary typo!

Comment: it is very bad practice to use try catch for what you are using it. Try using TryParse instead and get rid of the try catches.

Answer (score 5):

As someone said you gotta have line break after each Try

So change this line

```
   Try InterestRateDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InterestRateTextBox.text)
```

to

```
 Try
 InterestRateDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InterestRateTextBox.text)
```

as so does for every other Try.

Comment: I totally misunderstood @someone.. that worked!! I can't believe the book we're using doesn't mention that and shows the try statements on the same line!  Thank you both!

Comment: You can put both on the same line if they're separated by a colon, but it's more conventional to put them on separate lines.